# Multivariate logit: evaluate contributions of predictors to estimated probabilities

Tags: probability, logistic, classification, probit, multinomial-logit

In a logistic regression with multiple regressors, is there a way to analyze the contribution of the predictors on the dependent variable? (e.g. how would one understand why did the probabilities spike at certain point). Maybe one could use marginal probabilities at a given point?

Would using probit make any difference?

Comment: Is the relative size of the coefficient for that variable not what you want here?

Answer (score 0):

The concept is a simple generalization of how one would interpret a single predictor's effect on the probability scale.  The 3 main techniques from Agresti's Categorical Data Analysis are:

1. Consider a setting of predictors at which $\widehat{P}\left(Y=1\right) = \widehat{\pi}$.  Then, adjusting for other predictors, as a function of a quantitative predictor $x_j$, $\widehat{\pi}$ has instantaneous rate of change of $\widehat{\beta}_j \widehat{\pi}\left(1-\widehat{\pi}\right)$.  For instance, at predictor settings at which $\widehat{\pi}=.5$, the approximate effect of a 1-unit change of $x_j$ is $\frac{\widehat{\beta}_j}{4}$.
2. Summarize the effect of $x_j$ on the probability scale by averaging the instantaneous rates for the sample.  Let $x_{ij}$ denote the value of $x_j$ for subject $i$ and let $\widehat{\pi}\left(x_{i1},\cdots,x_{ip}\right)$ denote the estimate of $P(Y=1)$ at the explanatory variable values for subject $i$.  This summary is
   \begin{eqnarray*}
   \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \widehat{\beta}_j \widehat{\pi}\left(x_{i1},\cdots,x_{ip}\right) \left(1-\widehat{\pi}\left(x_{i1},\cdots,x_{ip}\right)\right).
   \end{eqnarray*}
3. Perhaps the simplest is to set all quantitative covariates at their mean values, considering separate cases for each distinct pattern of categorical covariates, and calculate the change in fitted probability when $x_j$ changes from its lower quartile to its upper quartile. For instance, if the fitted probabilities changed from .51 to .80 over the middle 50% values of the range of values of $x_j$, then it appears that this predictor has a strong influence on the probability scale.